# Pageshow deprecated in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I don't really understand what they're saying about [pageshow](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/) on the jQuery Mobile site:

> The triggering of this event is deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0.
>   It will no longer be triggered in 1.6.0. The replacement for pageshow
>   is the pagecontainer widget's pagecontainershow event. In jQuery
>   Mobile 1.4.0, the two events are identical except for their name and
>   the fact that pagecontainershow is triggered on the pagecontainer,
>   whereas pageshow is triggered on the page.

I don't think it's a matter of changing 'pageshow' to 'pagecontainershow'. I think it's a different selector, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You use the `$(":mobile-pagecontainer")` or `$(document)` or `$("body")` selectors

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
    var newPageID = ui.toPage.prop("id");
});
```

API Doc: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show

Then to see which page is being shown check the ui.toPage jQuery object.